# Why is Rayleigh scattering so much more likely than Stokes scattering?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, raman-spectroscopy

In Raman spectroscopy you have to deal with Rayleigh scattering and (Anti-)Stokes scattering. The intensity of Rayleigh scattering is about 5 magnitudes lower than the laser's excitation intensity, then the Stokes intensity is another 3 magnitudes lower and Anti-Stokes intensity another 3 magnitudes.

I understand that according to the Boltzmann distribution systems have lower probability of being in higher energy states. Since Anti-Stokes scattering requires a molecule to be in a higher energy state to begin with, it seems logical to me that this type of scattering is less likely than Rayleigh or Stokes scattering.

However Rayleigh and Stokes scattering both can start from the same energy state. Does the Boltzmann distribution also mean it is less likely for a molecule to end up in a higher state than it originally started? In other words: Does a molecule tend to try to emit as much energy as possible?

Comment: Boltzmann distribution is not relevant here - since in both cases one starts from the ground state. It would matter in terms of intensity of the incident light - if it comes from thermal radiation. However, there is frequency dependence, as well as selection rules, which are different for Rayleigh and Raman.

Comment: @RogerVadim I'm not sure if I understand correctly - the lower intensity of Stokes scattering is caused by the selection rules for the different vibrational and rotational levels. A change of vib. and rot. state is simply less likely than falling back to ground state?

Comment: Whether these are rotational, vibrational states or simply two atomic levels depends on the context/material. We begin in one state and end in the other (unlike for Rayleigh) which may have different symmetry - so not every transition allowed energetically would have a non-zero matrix element. However, I think that frequency dependence plays more important role here - there is a factor of $(\nu_0-\Delta\nu)^4/\nu_0^4$ between Stokes and Rayleigh or something like that (I am not sure about details, which is why I am not writing an answer.)